# Conjectured primality test for specific class of $N=4kp^n+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, counterexamples, conjectures

Can you provide a proof or counterexample for the following claim?

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $N= 4kp^{n}+1 $ where $k$ is a positive natural number , $ 4k<2^n$ , $p$ is a prime number and $n\ge3$ . Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{N}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{a+2}{N}\right)=-1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_p(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{kp^2}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} N$. Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytU8FymzAQvfsrFA5BAiU1JL3EVqcznd7aXNxbEnsEXowGkDSSiO168u-VAddx6oMP1Um7j_f2sbsqjGqQ3TZ6i0SjlXEoGq30LbzyGgcOrMMV1VQStntk91EV6bmMkwlnd5N1KWrAV7gySkJegcH8JqWPhLGbBF1fo3f5-JAnlMcxmczYT7XEaaRVnZeQbW0Jr3ivndKE8k8p8Z9PcmdYMlTx9ymTXv4sU3vW7MiKWUImosAzxsbUgGuNxM60QA5BwWsLhLwFZLSEAn0rvc3hNx9GyB9RoGrKxn2wPwPxB3ew-b7RBgfPz_7qdhVqWutQBmhlwKMGuZJL9BuMuvL6pFOA2gvK6d0FevK8nlt_lPOz-MLSKJIXiN4fXdZgbS-ZziX6aFE5LKw2ogGsCblAWf8V7lhItk0G5r2shaOML-FXq2hl7oSSi5zXw44F9Klr_wu5tXwF2O_KfmBH5lkT1hns20Bi7yZfKhfE-4z28by_7uRbB3ZW4wQJ29s8-vvX43-rlCv_nKxwQ7WvQvpp8tx1K7fAFRNSt26RqQ3-TMMKPYR0LZauZOmYUH2K6lNUnqLyFOVdd5mFGnKnDH4KuwUPX2jWOqekZb98b2nNM6hZGB7m3NMQQ93T7yOCOsiWaj1khmdC_gBeNEzK&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

I have verified this claim for $k \in [1,500]$ with $p \leq 97$ and $n \in [3,50]$ .

**Further generalization of the claim**

**A**

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $N= 2kp^{n} + 1 $ where $k$ is a positive natural number , $ 2k<2^n$ , $p$ is a prime number and $n\ge3$ . Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{N}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{a+2}{N}\right)=-1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_p(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{kp^2}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} N$. Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{n-2} \equiv -2 \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytk8Fy2jAQhu88hcIhlmwljc3kElCnM53eWi70lgRGNmussS1pJDlAmbx7hW0KpBw4RCdp1_-3v7Wr3Kga2W2tt0jUWhmHwsFK38Mbr_DQgXW4pJpKwnZTloRlqOcyisecjcbrQlSAb3BplISsBIP5XUKnhLG7GN3eopN4dIgTyqOIjGfsl1riJNSqygpIt7aAN7xnJzSm_EtC_OfjzBkW91X8fsKkx19Uaq-aHVURi8lY5HjG2NRLDLjGSOxMA-RwyHllgZD3IRksIUffC2-0_9GnAfJL5KicsIfusF-98Cd3sPmx0QYPX1781u1KVDfWoRTQyoDPGuQKLtEfMOrG80lLgMoD5WR0BU9e5rn1R5zvxlffklBeAU2OLiuwtkMmc4k-WlQOC6uNqAFrQq4g63_gVoVkU6dgTrEWjhhfwg9X3sjMCSUXGa_6KRvS5_b6X8m95SvAflr2DTsqL5qwzvhZKEnk3WRL5YbRPqL9ed5td_K9TbZWoxgJ29k8-vvf46dVypR_UFa4vto3IX03eebakVvgkgmpG7dI1QaPaFCip4CuxdIVLHkgVJ9kH2mgz7PyXCvPs7y9XWahgswpg5-DdsCDV5o2zilp2W9_t7TiKVQsCA597mSIofbxdyeC2pQt1LqP9M-E_AVwpE05&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

**B**

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . 
>   Let $N= 2kp^{n} - 1 $ where $k$ is a positive natural number , $ 2k<2^n$ , $p$ is a prime number and $n\ge3$ . Let $a$ be a natural number greater than two such that $\left(\frac{a-2}{N}\right)=1$ and $\left(\frac{a+2}{N}\right)=-1$ where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ denotes Jacobi symbol. Let $S_i=P_p(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0$ equal to the modular $P_{kp^2}(a)\phantom{5} \text{mod} \phantom{5} N$. Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{n-2} \equiv -2 \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJytU8Fy2jAQvfMVCodYskUam8kloE5nOr21XOgtCYxs1lhjW9JIcoAy-fcK2ymQcuAQnXb3-b191q5yo2pkd7XeIVFrZRwKB2t9B6-8wkMH1uGSaioJ289YEpahXshRPOFsPNkUogJ8g0ujJGQlGMxHCZ0RxmJ0e4tOylFXHsWE8igikzn7pVY4CbWqsgLSnS3gFR-kExpT_iUh_vNJ5gyL-yY-njLp1S8ytWfNj6yIxWQicjxnbOYpBlxjJHamAfKe5LyyQMjbkAxWkKPvhTfa_-fjAPkjclRO2X2XHE5P_MkdbH9stcHD52cfun2J6sY6lAJaG_CoQa7gEv0Bo268PmkVoPKCcjq-Qk9e1nObj3J-GF_9REJ5hWhydFmBtZ1kspDoo0XlsLDaiBqwJuQKZf1PuGUh2dQpmFNZC0cZ38LvVt7IzAkllxmv-iUb0qf2-l_IneVrwH5bDgM7Mi-asM74XShJ5N1kK-WG0aGifb7owr18a8HW6ihGwnY2j_7-9_hpnTLl35MVru_2TUg_TZ65duWWuGRC6sYtU7XFYxqU6DGgG7FyBUvuCdUn6AMN9Dkqz1F5jvL2dpmFCjKnDH4K2gUPXmjaOKekZb_93dKKp1CxIHifc0dDDLVvv8sIaiFbqE1f6Z8J-Quze00U&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "if and only if" statement fails for 
$$[p,n,k,a] \in \{ [3, 4, 1, 100], [3, 4, 1, 225], [3, 6, 13, 2901] \}$$ and many others. In these cases, $N$ is not prime, but the congruence $S_{n-2}\equiv 0\pmod{N}$ still holds.