# Primality test for specific class of $N=12k \cdot 5^n-1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elementary-proofs

Can you provide a proof for the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^m\right)$ .

> Let $N= 12k \cdot 5^{n} - 1 $ where  $n\ge3$ , $12k <5^n$ and

> $\begin{cases} k \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 0,3,4 \pmod{6} \\ 
> k \equiv 2 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 0,2,5 \pmod{6} \\ 
> k \equiv 3 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 1,4,5 \pmod{6} \\
> k \equiv 4 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 1,2,4 \pmod{6} \\
> k \equiv 5 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 2,3,5 \pmod{6} \\ 
> k \equiv 6 \pmod{7} \text{ with } n \equiv 0,1,3 \pmod{6} \end{cases}$

> Let $S_i=S_{i-1}^5-5S_{i-1}^3+5S_{i-1}$ with $S_0=P_{75k}(5)$, then $N$ is a prime iff $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtjkELgjAcxe99CvMg25rUJqNg_rt06pAE3oPUhUPdZA6jb988VJdu7_0eP3gdZEwaOGRypR-IcdLl4maiJInMkdMCFkICSZks4WIbxMlo-7pV1Wtq1Yz2gnSUUbHlmBZY1t4Bk89W9wqFnINJOf0rimCVP2sDDMvwoATY0dFp41F8dXpQ6xh_-skOo520X9gXns1873UTKeOdVtMyyTeNYj-P&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). I have verified this claim for $k \in [1,111]$ with $n \in [3,1000]$ .